# Typescript how get optional keys of type

Tags: typescript

There is a type

```
{ a: string, b: number, c?: string, d?: number }
```

How to get the type

```
'c' | 'd'
```

from this?

Answer (score 6):

Finally I found the solution based on [Typescript how to create type with common properties of two types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47375916/typescript-how-to-create-type-with-common-properties-of-two-types)

```
type MappedC<A, B> = {
  [K in keyof A & keyof B]:
  A[K] extends B[K]
    ? never
    : K
};

type OptionalKeys<T> = MappedC<T, Required<T>>[keyof T];
```

But it works like a magic, because when combining these two types into one and replacing B by Required it stops working.

Other solution, which seems to be more stable:

```
export type KeysOfType<T, U> = { [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends U ? K : never }[keyof T];
export type RequiredKeys<T> = Exclude<KeysOfType<T, Exclude<T[keyof T], undefined>>, undefined>;
export type OptionalKeys<T> = Exclude<keyof T, RequiredKeys<T>>;
```

Comment: These are actually different solutions. Take for example this:

```ts
type Foo = { a: string; b: string | undefined; c?: string };
```

The former solution (based on `Mapped`) will return (the expected): `'c'`.
The latter solution (based on `RequiredKeys`) will return (the unexpected): `'b' | 'c'`.