# Is it possible to make an "inner join" on interfaces

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Let's say we have two interfaces `First` and `Second`:

```js
interface First {
  a: string;
  b: number;
}

interface Second {
  b: number;
  c: Date;
}
```

With intersections it is possible to merge two interfaces:

```js
type FirstSecond = First & Second // {a: string, b: number, c: Date}
```

But is it possible to make an *inner join*, so the resultant interface **only** consists of properties that are declared in **both** interfaces:

```js
type FirstSecond = First /*inner join here*/ Second // {b: number}
```

This could especially be helpful for generic types.

Comment: Why don't you extract the common interface?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47375916/typescript-how-to-create-type-with-common-properties-of-two-types

Comment: @jonrsharpe idk what you telling me to do? If it would be that simple for me I would not ask a question here. If you mean that I should declare a third interface like `{ b:  number }` then it's not answering my question because I wanted to have a generic solution (see last sentence).

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I mean, extract a third interface with the commonalities.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `Pick` to take the common properties from the intersection. To get the common properties, you can use the `Extract` conditional type to filter the keys of one type by the keys of the other:

```
interface First {
  a: string;
  b: number;
}

interface Second {
  b: number;
  c: Date;
}


type IntersectByProperties<T, U> = Pick<T & U, Extract<keyof T, keyof U>>

type R = IntersectByProperties<First, Second>
```