# Extends keyof Type Intersection

Tags: typescript

Lets say I want to write a simple generic join function.

```
const join = <X, Y, T extends keyof (X & Y)>(key: T, a1: Array<X>, a2: Array<Y>) =>
    a1.map(e1 => [ e1, a2.find(e2 => e2[key] === e1[key]) ])
```

`T` should be a string which specifies on which attribute the function should join.

Sadly I get an error: `T cannot be used to index type Y`

This is weird since `X & Y` is the intersection type thus all keys generated by the extends keyof expression should apply on X and on Y.

Answer (score 0):

I guess, your assumption about the intersection type is wrong:

```js
interface X  {
    x: number
};
interface Y {
    y: number
}
type Inter = X & Y;
type InterK = keyof Inter; // = 'x' | 'y'
```

What you actually want is to get only the types that are the same in both types.

for description of `Common<>` see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47379147/1041641

```js
type Common<A, B> = {
    [P in keyof A & keyof B]: A[P] | B[P];
}

interface X2  {
    x: number
};
interface Y2 {
    y: number,
    x: string
}
type Inter2 = Common<X2, Y2>;
type InterK2 = keyof Inter2; // = 'x'
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgBrOQbwFAYwDwC5kQBXAWwCNpsBfAbm1ElkRQE0tc8BPYsqjVrYwPAA4oAkuGjIAvGmQAyZO0aiJyaSwDS85AGsIPAPYwtMqPWQB6G-oDk+B8gA+yBzwfYR4lAGETcnITEAAeAEEAGmQAIQA+fRw8ZABtAAVkUENjM2QI5RzTc1iAXWIIjNK3OKrGYSZLeCQ0ACYMZLwiEgpqKDpGZmhmjnbOjD4ewSgo7gJiAGcwKFAAczpfTW1odoVA4NCw1FaY9lb49T8LXV2ivO2oVus7R2cgA)